# Locking an android tablet to a specific website

Tags: android, galaxy-tab

in IOS I can create a shortcut to my web app on the main screen, and then use guided access to lock the tablet to that single website.

Can the same thing be achieved somehow with android?

Comment: Short answer yes. Short question, what have you tried?

Comment: @wtsang02 - Thanks for the reply, I don't have an android tablet, so am unable to try. One of my customers has asked whether this is possible with my web application.

Comment: It can't be done on Android. You sure can lock the user to a single app (using third-party apps), but you can not block her from navigating to other web sites.

Comment: When you say web application, do you mean a native application that wraps a WebView? If so, you can override the loading of urls

Comment: @funkthemonk - no, just a web url you enter in a browser.